# Serving static files with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have one page website only using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I want to deploy the app to Heroku, but I cannot find a way to do it. I am now trying to make the app working with Sinatra.

```
.
|-- application.css
|-- application.js
|-- index.html
|-- jquery.js
`-- myapp.rb
```

And the following is the content of `myapp.rb`.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get "/" do
  # What should I write here to point to the `index.html`
end
```

Comment: I have learnt that accessing http://localhost:2345/index.html works.

Comment: You can use WebBrick to serve static files in a few lines. `require 'webrick'; server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new Port: 1234; server.mount '/', WEBrick::HTTPServlet::FileHandler, 'www/'; trap("INT") { server.stop }; server.start;` Then run `ruby myapp.rb`. Remove the port for Heroku. Put `web: ruby myapp.rb` in your `Procfile`. Comment not answer as it's not for Sinatra, but I think it simplifies dependencies.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Without any additional configuration, Sinatra will serve assets in `public`. For the empty route, you'll want to render the index document.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  File.read(File.join('public', 'index.html'))
end
```

Routes should return a `String` which become the HTTP response body. `File.read` opens a file, reads the file, closes the file and returns a `String`.

Comment: You should rather do `send_file File.expand_path('index.html', settings.public)`.

Comment: This is now incorrect. You should replace `settings.public` with `settings.public_folder` to get `send_file File.expand_path('index.html', settings.public_folder)`

Comment: @zhirzh `send_file`, it does extra stuff for you https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L351

Comment: `File.read` reads the entire file into memory.  This can be OK or not, depending upon the size of the files and the number of concurrent requests.

Comment: @WayneConrad on the opposite, send_file is okay ? or it acts the same ?

Comment: @Ben I do not know, but I would be surprised if `send_file` did not handle large files gracefully.

Answer (score 169):

You can use the `send_file` helper to serve files.

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  send_file File.join(settings.public_folder, 'index.html')
end
```

This will serve `index.html` from whatever directory has been configured as having your application's static files.

Comment: I think newer Sinatra apps use `set :public_folder`, so you would use `settings.public_folder` instead of `settings.public`

Comment: I updated the answer to use settings.public_folder. Older apps may still need to use settings.public.

Answer (score 65):

You could just host them from the public folder and they do not need routes.

```
.
-- myapp.rb
`-- public
    |-- application.css
    |-- application.js
    |-- index.html
    `-- jquery.js
```

In the myapp.rb

```
set :public_folder, 'public'

get "/" do
  redirect '/index.html'
end
```

Link to some sub folder in public

```
set :public_folder, 'public'
get "/" do
  redirect '/subfolder/index.html' 
end
```

Everything in ./public is accessible from '/whatever/bla.html

Example :
./public/stylesheets/screen.css
Will be accessible via '/stylesheets/screen.css' no route required

Comment: what if public has many nested folders (for which you don't want to create routes) that have index.html files you would like to be the default?

Comment: I have expanded the solution. I hope it helps clarify, everything is accessible in public, no route required just omit the 'public' part of the path.

Comment: using rackup on Heroku I had to use `set :public_folder, 'public'`. That was key to making it work, despite Sinatra documentation implying that this was already set as default.

Answer (score 12):

Keep in mind that in production you can have your web server send out `index.html` automatically so that the request never gets to Sinatra. This is better for performance as you don't have to go through the Sinatra/Rack stack just to serve static text, which is what Apache/Nginx are awesome at doing.

Comment: Oh yeah, duh. I'll just use Erb then and use Varnish to cash it.

Comment: How do you configure this in production? I've been searching for documentation about this cross referencing with Sinatra and Rack but can't find it. Basically I want index.html to be loaded in any /public folder that has one if the user only puts the folder name

Answer (score 11):

Sinatra should let you serve static files from the public directory [as explained in the docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html):

> **Static Files**
>
> Static files are served from the ./public directory. You can specify a different location by setting the :public option:
>
> Note that the public directory name is not included in the URL. A file ./public/css/style.css is made available as example.com/css/style.css.

Comment: Why does this have 4 votes? It doesn't answer the question of how to present a default document when a folder is requested.

Answer (score 6):

Add below line in main rb file

```
set :public_folder, 'public'
```

ref: http://sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#static---enabledisable-static-file-routes

Answer (score 3):

http://sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#static---enabledisable-static-file-routes

This would be the correct way of doing it.

```
set :public_folder, 'public'
```

I used the static setting because it's setting can affect the public_folder usage.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use Rack::Static

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Static

Just add this line before 'run' command into 'config.ru'

```
use Rack::Static, :urls => [""], :root => 'public', :index => 'index.html'
```

Answer (score 2):

the [sinatra-assetpack](https://github.com/rstacruz/sinatra-assetpack) gem offers a whole bunch of features. syntax is sweet:

```
serve '/js', from: '/app/javascripts'
```

while i am still having issues with rails assets pipeline i feel like i have much more control using [sinatra-assetpack](https://github.com/rstacruz/sinatra-assetpack) - but most of the times it just works with a few lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED ANSWER**: 
I tied all the above with no luck of being ablle to load css, js....etc contents the only thing that was loading is index.html... and the rest were going =>> `404 error`

My solution: app folder looks like this .

`index.rb`  ==>> Sinatra code goes .

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  html :index
end

def html(view)
  File.read(File.join('public', "#{view.to_s}.html"))
end
```

`public folder`==>> contains everything else ...css , js , blah blah..etc.

```
user@user-SVE1411EGXB:~/sintra1$ ls
index.rb  public
user@user-SVE1411EGXB:~/sintra1$ find public/
public/
public/index.html
public/about_us.html
public/contact.html
public/fonts
public/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg
public/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf
public/img
public/img/drink_ZIDO.jpg
public/js
public/js/bootstrap.min.js
public/js/jquery.min.js
public/js/bootstrap.js
public/carsoul2.html
public/css
public/css/font-awesome-ie7.css
public/css/bootstrap.min.css
public/css/font-awesome.min.css
public/css/bootstrap.css
public/css/font-awesome.css
public/css/style.css
user@user-SVE1411EGXB:~/sintra1$
```

Now start server and you will be able to navigate through static pages with no problem.

```
user@user-SVE1411EGXB:~/sintra1$ ruby index.rb 
== Sinatra/1.4.5 has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on localhost:4567, CTRL+C to stop
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

set :public_folder, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../client'
#client - it's folder with all your file, including myapp.rb

get "/" do
  File.read('index.html')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider moving the `index.html` file to `views/index.erb`, and defining an endpoint like:

```
get '/' do
  erb :index
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting files in `public` folder has a limitation. Actually, when you are in the root `'/'` path is works correctly because the browser will set the relative path of your css file for example `/css/style.css` and sinatra will look for the file in the `public` directory. However, if your location is for example `/user/create`, then the web browser will look for your css file in `/user/create/css/style.css` and will the fail.

As a workaround, I added the following redirection to correctly load css file:

```
get %r{.*/css/style.css} do
    redirect('css/style.css')
end
```

Answer (score -7):

What about this solution? :

```
get "/subdirectory/:file" do 
  file = params[:file] + "index.html"
  if File.exists?(params[:file])
    return File.open("subdirectory/" + file)
  else
   return "error"
  end
end
```

so if you now navigate to (for example) /subdirectory/test/  it will load subdirectory/test/index.html