# How to render a plain HTML file with Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a simple sinatra application. All I want to do is use it as a wrapper to serve a static HTML file at a specific route. My directory structure looks like this:

```
/directory
    myhtmlfile.html
    app.rb
```

My `app.rb` file looks like this:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/myspecialroute' do
    html :myhtmlfile      # i know html is not a method, but this is what I would like to do
end
```

How can I write this so that I can keep my html file a plain html file but serve it at a special route?

### Solution:

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437390/serving-static-files-with-sinatra), I learned a few different ways to do it:

```
get '/myspecialroute' do
  File.read('myhtmlfile.html')
end
```

This will open, read, close, then return the file as a string.

Or there is a helper function to make this cleaner:

```
get '/myspecialroute' do
  send_file 'myhtmlfile.html'
end
```

Comment: You could change it to .erb and then call the erb method with no erb in it.

Comment: Do you want it to render the HTML file when requesting `'/myspecialroute'` or `'/myspecialroute.html'`?

Comment: @tbuehlmann I would like the route to stay `/myspecialroute`

Comment: If all you're using Sinatra for is serving a static HTML file, why are you using Sinatra at all?

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser To start up a zero-configuration web server on an available port. Also to add a special route. Do you have any alternatives?

Comment: I thought you meant that you'd only be serving the one static file. If that's the case, how about [pow](http://pow.cx/) or some other simple server?

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser Pow is cool. I use that for local development. But I didn't want it to be on port 80. Also, I wanted to share this page with my co-workers. So they could go to http://my.ip.address:4567/myspecialroute

Comment: Is https://github.com/37signals/pow/issues/60 helpful?

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser If I could set a different port in a project specific config file, it would be perfect, but I don't see a way to do that out of the box.

Comment: Hmm. There's gotta be a lightweight server that can do that. Sinatra seems like overkill if you're not using server-side logic.

Comment: How about WEBrick? I know it somehow seems passé, but it might be what you need here. See http://onestepback.org/index.cgi/Tech/Ruby/WEBrick.rdoc .

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Does [send_file](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sinatra/1.3.1/Sinatra/Helpers#send_file-instance_method) do what you want?

e.g.

```
  get '/myspecialroute' do
     send_file 'special.html'
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
get '/myspecialroute' do
  redirect '/myspecialroute.html'
end
```

Comment: that will cause a redirect. I would like to stay at the route originally requested.

Comment: is there a way to just load up the file contents and return it?

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575389/static-page-routing-in-sinatra-ruby/2575415#2575415

Answer (score 1):

This is work for me:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/index.html' do
    @page_title = 'Home'
    @page_id = 'index.html'
    erb :'index.html', { :layout => :'layout.html' }
end
```