# Rendering HTML file in Views folder results in a string, Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have admin.html in my views folder. How do I get to render it by

```
get '/admin/?' do
    require_logged_in
    send_file 'views/admin.html' //??
end
```

but even while following "[How to render a plain HTML file with Sinatra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997081/how-to-render-a-plain-html-file-with-sinatra)", I end up with the text of the markup, not the rendered HTML. How do I load a view from here?

Secondly, is it "the right thing to do" to put my views there, I mean I feel that it shouldn't be put in the public folder, I've tried putting admin.html in the public folder and I am able to render it just fine. Should I put this in the views folder or the public folder?

Comment: Big hint when writing text for the web or a question on SO: Don't say "this" for anchor text in a link. Use the title of the page or paragraph, or something descriptive. Links to Stack Overflow pages will render correctly so just wrap them in double-quotes.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it. It turns out that I had

```
content_type :json
```

up in a `before` block. I added content_type "html", everything's good now.