# Displaying .txt file with Ruby Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I would simply like to display a .txt file located in my public directory onto a page. I apologise that this may seem novice but I am new to Ruby.

So far the ruby sinatra code reads:

```
get '/create' do
    logfile = File.open("logfile.txt")
    erb :create
end
```

and the erb reads:

```
<h2>Text file:</h2>
<%= logfile %>
```

Can someone tell me what I need to display this text file on my page?

Comment: I got same type of smell here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997081/how-to-render-a-plain-html-file-with-sinatra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as below :

## sinatra code :

```
get '/create' do
    @logfile = File.open("logfile.txt","r")
    erb :create
    @logfile.close
end
```

## file.erb

```
<h2>Text file:</h2>
<% @logfile.each_line do |line| %>
  <%= line %>
<% end %>
```

Or you can use [`File#read`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/IO.html#method-i-read) :

## file.erb

```
<h2>Text file:</h2>
<%= @logfile.read %>
```

Comment: This keeps the file open through the entire HTTP request. This isn't necessarily a problem per se, but I personally get nervous when I don't see an explicit close. (I prefer block-form `open` or in this case `read` instead).

Comment: @MarkThomas Very good point indeed. I did it this way, as I don't know the file content, so I thought let the file pass to the erb as a object. Then inside the view, I will read the lines. Now point is, I need to close the file. If I put `@logfile.close` after `erb :create`, hope it would makes sense. Am I right ?

Answer (score 6):

Another way to show `.txt` file with `Sinatra`(without `erb`).

in your script:

```
get '/' do
  send_file 'views/file.txt'
end
```

puts `file.txt` with content:

```
Heloo ! somebody here?
```

[image]

Comment: How can this be printed in the `.erb` view page ? You are changing the OP's file system or project structure. The file is *public* folder.

Comment: that is requested OP `Can someone tell me what I need to display this text file on my page?`

Comment: If what the OP wants is just the text, this is the simplest way to do it. If he wants to incorporate it as part of a page, it will require a view.

Comment: @MarkThomas I totally agree. Just another way.

Comment: People up voting you means,, I am not correct. Could you explain how your code displaying the text file, in the `.erb` view page ? I am really interested to get the explanations.

Comment: @ArupRakshit there is no `.erb`, i just provide some another way `Displaying .txt file with Ruby Sinatra`.somebody can search this .

Comment: Ok... Please mention it in your answer, that your answer is another trick. Otherwise, future readers wouldn't be able to connect your answer with the post mention here. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

I think you were aiming for something like this:

```
get '/create' do
    @logfile = File.read("logfile.txt")
    erb :create
end
```

In the Erb:

```
<h2>Text file:</h2>
<%= @logfile %>
```

(Note that I would probably also put it inside a `div` with `overflow: auto` style applied)

Comment: Yes.. This is Ok.. +1

Comment: Sorry, I misread.. I read `File.read("logfile.txt")` as `File.readlines("logfile.txt")`....

Answer (score 0):

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692921/how-to-html-encode-escape-a-string-is-there-a-built-in) applied a secure solution as I need to output the text file inside my other HTML.

```
require 'rack/utils'

get '/logfile' do
    File.open('./public/log.txt','r') do |file|
        @logtext = Rack::Utils.escape_html(file.read) # this will assure security
    end
    erb :logfile
end
```

`views/logfile.erb`

```
<h1>Log file</h1>
<pre><%= @logtext %></pre>
```

Suppose our logs are less secure than our site code, and some bad person did a bad thing:

```
[INFO] User Admin successfully logged in.
[ERROR] User Frog failed to log in.
</pre><script>alert('Do harmful thing!')</script>
[INFO] User Admin successfully logged in.
```

The output will be exactly the above text (without the pop-up message).