# Config.ru running as server not reading html

Tags: html, ruby, sinatra

I recently began programming and learning Ruby and JavaScript and was attempting to read my html file through my Sinatra server using a `config.ru` file.

The server runs, its hitting all the routes but I think there may be something wrong with the server code for the index page:

```
get("/") do
  content_type :html
  File.read( File.expand_path("../views/index.html", __FILE__) )
end
```

Comment: What exactly wrong with your server? index page not load ?

Comment: Yea that's exactly it. Seems rudimentary but I can't figure it out. I didn't write the code for the server and I'm not sure if there's an error that I'm not seeing

Comment: Using console in Google Chrome I can see the html is being loaded at 1280px X 8px

Comment: i do not understand your last comment but you can use `send_file` method like this `send_file File.read(....)`

Comment: So:  send_file(File.read( File.expand_path("../views/index.html", __FILE__) )) ?

Comment: try this `send_file('views/index.html')`

Comment: The console in Google Chrome which you can use to interact with the DOM and manipulate using javascript/jQuery. Under its Elements tab I can see all the html loaded into the browser. It shows my html file is being read but I can't seem to interact with it and its loaded the length of the browser (1280p) but oddly at height 8p

Answer (score 1):

Put `index.html` in `public` folder. Sinatra will serve files in `public` as is. So you need to request it directly e.g. [http://localhost/**index.html**](http://localhost/index.html).

If you want to handle empty route i.e. `get '/'` use snippet below (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437390/serving-static-files-with-sinatra)):

```
get '/' do
  send_file File.join(settings.public_folder, 'index.html')
end
```

In order to be sure in `settings.public_folder` please check does it work correctly, does it return correct path.

Cheers!